# npm list -g shows packages I haven't installed

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm ls -g` shows a ton a packages and i havent installed any of them except 1 or two.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bCRv.png)

the package.json in my home directory:

```
{
  "name": "yash",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

the node_modules folder in my home directory is empty.

so what are all these files?

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-g` flag will show **global** packages. These are packages which are not included in your `package.json` but are instead either packaged with your installation or were installed with `npm install -g`.

If the global packages you install have their own dependencies, then you'll also see those child dependencies listed. For example, you can see you installed `nodemon`, so you'll also see `chokidar` in the list, since `nodemon` requires that package to work.

If you want to ignore the child dependencies and see only the packages you directly installed, you can use `npm list -g --depth 0`.

You can [read more about global packages vs. local packages](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages)